# How to sum columns of rows in index which match a certain column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm working on a dataset of US elections, and want to find the two-party vote total. I have indexed races by `state_dist`, which is a three or four letter string. First two letters indicate which state, the third (and fourth if applicable) indicate which congressional district within the state. I have reduced the dataset to just ones with a single Democrat and Republican, as well as independent and third party candidates who aren't of interest.

The two-party vote is essentially the total of the `candidate_vote` column in each `state_dist` entry's rows with a Democrat and a Republican. So if the Democrat got 1000 votes, the Republican 2000, and an independent 50, the two-party vote is 3000. I want to output this value for every `state_dist`, indexed by `state_dist`

One extra piece of information: the North Dakota Democrats are listed as the `"DEMOCRATIC-NPL"` party and the Minnesota Democrats are listed as the `"DEMOCRATIC-FARMER-LABOR"` party. All Republicans are just listed as `"REPUBLICAN"` and all other Democrats are `"DEMOCRAT"`

Here is a screenshot of the dataframe, named `results_pure`:

[image]

How should I go about this? Either summing by index value for rows with "DEMOCRATIC-NPL"`,` "DEMOCRATIC-FARMER-LABOR"`,` "REPUBLICAN"`or`"DEMOCRAT"`values in the`"party"`column could work, or perhaps removing all with other`"party"` values then summing by index. But I'm inexperienced on complex index operations like this, and a bit stumped.

Thanks for the help.

A sample of the dataframe:

```
    state   state_po    state_fips  district    special candidate   party   writein mode    candidatevotes  totalvotes  abnormal
state_dist                                              

AL1 ALABAMA AL  1   1   False   ROBERT KENNEDY JR.  DEMOCRAT    False   TOTAL   89226   242617  0
AL1 ALABAMA AL  1   1   False   BRADLEY BYRNE   REPUBLICAN  False   TOTAL   153228  242617  0
AL1 ALABAMA AL  1   1   False   NaN NaN True    TOTAL   163 242617  0
AL2 ALABAMA AL  1   2   False   MARTHA ROBY REPUBLICAN  False   TOTAL   138879  226230  0
AL2 ALABAMA AL  1   2   False   TABITHA ISNER   DEMOCRAT    False   TOTAL   86931   226230  0
AL2 ALABAMA AL  1   2   False   NaN NaN True    TOTAL   420 226230  0
AL3 ALABAMA AL  1   3   False   MIKE ROGERS REPUBLICAN  False   TOTAL   147770  231915  0
AL3 ALABAMA AL  1   3   False   MALLORY HAGAN   DEMOCRAT    False   TOTAL   83996   231915  0
AL3 ALABAMA AL  1   3   False   NaN NaN True    TOTAL   149 231915  0
AL4 ALABAMA AL  1   4   False   ROBERT ADERHOLT REPUBLICAN  False   TOTAL   184255  230969  0
```

Comment: Instead of posting the screenshot, post a sample dataframe.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh I have added the first ten columns as a sample

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured this out.

First, remove all candidates from parties I don't want. This was done by resetting the e index and filtering new datasets with each Democratic party, and the Republican party, then joining them back together in Excel. Once they were back together, I used:

```
df.groupby("state_dist").sum()
```

and took the column of `candidatevotes`, which had the sum of Democratic and Republican candidates' votes, ie. the two-party-vote total.